# Problem with ElseIf - Select-String statement in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I am new to PowerShell so please bear with me.
In the code below I am trying to capture any of the 3 specific error messages (or all) from a log and send email(s). I don't get any error, but I don't receive any email.
For testing purposes I have created a txt file called `Nikos_text2.txt` where I have put all 3 error messages.

Here is the code:

```
$File = 'D:\...\...\logs\Nikos_text2.txt'
    
If ($File | Select-String 'Trigger action error') {
    
    $smtp = new-object Net.Mail.SmtpClient("server name")
    $objMailMessage = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage
    $objMailMessage.From = "op-support@domain.com"
    $objMailMessage.To.Add("nikolaos@domain.com")
    $objMailMessage.To.Add("nikolaos@domain.com")
    $objMailMessage.Subject = "Error message: 'Trigger action error'"
    $objMailMessage.Body = "In log in server (SI) I traced the following error message: Trigger action error. Pls check it asap"
    $smtp.send($objMailMessage)
}
ElseIf ($File | Select-String 'Connection refused') {
   
    $smtp = new-object Net.Mail.SmtpClient("server name")
    $objMailMessage = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage
    $objMailMessage.From = "op-support@domain.com"
    $objMailMessage.To.Add("nikolaos@domain.com")
    $objMailMessage.To.Add("nikolaos@domain.com")
    $objMailMessage.Subject = "Error message: 'Connection refused'"
    $objMailMessage.Body = "In log in server (SI) I traced the following error message: Connection refused. Pls check it asap"
    $smtp.send($objMailMessage)
}
ElseIf ($File | Select-String 'Content is not allowed in Prolog') {
    
    $smtp = new-object Net.Mail.SmtpClient("server name")
    $objMailMessage = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage
    $objMailMessage.From = "op-support@domain.com"
    $objMailMessage.To.Add("nikolaos@domain.com")
    $objMailMessage.To.Add("nikolaos@domain.com")
    $objMailMessage.Subject = "Error message: 'Content is not allowed in Prolog'"
    $objMailMessage.Body = "In log in server (SI) the following error message was traced: Content is not allowed in Prolog. Pls check it asap"
    $smtp.send($objMailMessage)
}
Else {
    break 
}
```

Could anyone please give me a hint what am I doing wrong or whether I am forgetting something?

Comment: `$File | Get-Content | Select-String ..`

Comment: Hi iRon, thank you for your reply. Unfortunately after adding the Get-Content I get an error: "The input object cannot be bound to any parameters for the command...."

Answer (score 2):

Variable $File does not contain the content of your file but the name. Using
$File = Get-Content 'D:......\logs\Nikos_text2.txt'
will solve your problem.

Comment: Hi matandra, thank you very much for your reply, it worked and learned something today! Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

Your `Select-String` input is the path, not the file content, so you will never get a match. You have to first get the content and then operate on that.

```
$content = Get-Content $File

If ($content | Select-String 'Trigger action error') {
```

Actually you don't really need `Select-String` as you are not interested in the match result, but instead just want to know if there is a match. Even RegEx is overkill, so I would use the [`-like`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.1#-like-and--notlike) operator instead:

```
If ($content -like '*Trigger action error*') {
```

You may also look into [`switch -wildcard -file`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_switch?view=powershell-7.1) as an alternative way to solve the problem.

Comment: Hi zett42, thank you very much for your reply also! It also works and now I think that I understood better what was the issue in my code!
Thank you again!